# Auto expand qcombobox that is delegate in qtreeview

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qtreeview, qcombobox

I have my own QTreeModel implemented, where at first column I'm using custom delegate which is QComboBox with auto-completion of some strings in it.
The delegate is created by using
`QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index);` method.
Also, the delegate is being created only when adding new rows to certain tree model item.
My question is whether and how is it possible to auto-expand list of items to choose in created QComboBox editor after adding new item with it to tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enter edit mode, you can use:

```
void QAbstractItemView::edit(const QModelIndex &index)
```

The combobox will be shown, but not opened. To do that, you can override `QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData()` and call `combobox->showPopup();` at the end of the function.

```
void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // check correct index for combobox

    QComboBox *combobox = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(editor);
    combobox->setCurrentText(index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString());
    combobox->showPopup();
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. To get 1 step closer however you can call the `edit()` method on the QTableView when the current index changes, or an item is selected. That way it doesn't require a double-click to show the popup, but just a single click.